# Create ViewGroup of ImageView and TextView and display it in FlowLayout Programmatically - Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, viewgroup, flowlayout

I have a Flow layout that display 4 objects for row, but I need display these 4 objects with a textview below each one of them. But it display 2 images and 2 textview, and junp to another row. I tryed to create a ViewGroup to display them together, but I got the same isue. Maybe if I try to set location of the textView inside of the group It canal work, but I dont know How to do it.

What I got:
[image: What I got:]

What I want:
[image: What I want:]

My XML:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svLikes"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:background="#3c4052"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnAdd"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

    <com.nex3z.flowlayout.FlowLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        app:childSpacingForLastRow="align"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        app:rowSpacing="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/likesContainer"
        >

    </com.nex3z.flowlayout.FlowLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

My code:

```
ImageView iconLike = new ImageView(Register30.this);
            TextView txtLike = new TextView(Register30.this);

            iconLike.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.x));
            txtLike.setText("Unable");


            countLikesAdd++;
            removeMessageOrShow();


            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(140,130);
            lp.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
            iconLike.setLayoutParams(lp);
            txtLike.setLayoutParams(lp);
            txtLike.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            fieldLike.setText("");
            ViewGroup gp = new LinearLayout(Register30.this);
            gp.addView(iconLike);
            gp.addView(txtLike);
            likesContainer.addView(gp);
```

Comment: do you want the desired effect only using flowlayout library?

Comment: Sorry. I didnt get It... I want to the flowlayout thinks that imageview and textView be one obj only.

Comment: if you have fixed number of item define your layout in xml or if dynamic use gridview

Comment: I don't have a fixed number of obj to add. It can be add programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Method : Static Way**
I think what you need is a drawable image on TextView. The drawable image can be inserted in any position except center. Create a suitable image of required sizes form [asset studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) and use this line on TextView.

> android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_fb_logo_blue_48dp"

A simple implementation is written in below code.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/svLikes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.nex3z.flowlayout.FlowLayout
                    android:id="@+id/likesContainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    app:childSpacingForLastRow="align"
                    app:rowSpacing="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_fb_logo_blue_48dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/facebook"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_fb_logo_blue_48dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/facebook"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_fb_logo_blue_48dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/facebook"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_fb_logo_blue_48dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/facebook"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                </com.nex3z.flowlayout.FlowLayout>

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The output image is below. I have used NestedScrollView Instead of ScrollView. 
[image]

**Second Method : Dynamic**
Programmatically a number of views can be generated by using grid layout. My implemenation using recylerview is below

Inside Activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerOne = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    initRecyclerView();

    //update whenever necessary
    adapterOne.updateItems(myList);
}

private void initRecyclerView(){
    //Datum is model class
    int spanCount = 4; // 4 columns in grid
    int spacing = 8;
    boolean includeEdge = true;

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, spanCount);
    recyclerOne.setHasFixedSize(false);
    recyclerOne.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    recyclerOne.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount, spacing, includeEdge));
    adapterOne = new RecylcerViewAdapter(new ArrayList<Datum>());
    recyclerOne.setAdapter(adapterOne);
}
```

The **GridSpacingItemDecoration** class is

```
public class GridSpacingItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private int spanCount;
private int spacing;
private boolean includeEdge;

public GridSpacingItemDecoration(int spanCount, int spacing, boolean includeEdge) {
    this.spanCount = spanCount;
    this.spacing = spacing;
    this.includeEdge = includeEdge;
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view); // item position
    int column = position % spanCount; // item column

    if (includeEdge) {
        outRect.left = spacing - column * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
        outRect.right = (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // (column + 1) * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)

        if (position < spanCount) { // top edge
            outRect.top = spacing;
        }
        outRect.bottom = spacing; // item bottom
    } else {
        outRect.left = column * spacing / spanCount; // column * ((1f / spanCount) * spacing)
        outRect.right = spacing - (column + 1) * spacing / spanCount; // spacing - (column + 1) * ((1f /    spanCount) * spacing)
        if (position >= spanCount) {
            outRect.top = spacing; // item top
        }
    }
}
```

}

Inside recycler view adapter class, during binding view use a single textview with drawable image as in first method and update data. For updating whole list you create following function and call it from activity class:

```
public void updateItems(List<Datum> data) {
    list.clear()
    list.addAll(data)
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Other methods**
There is also one other method I know which is done by inflating an item and adding the inflated view on the already created linearlayout(or any other container layouts).

Use whatever methods you like. Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 1):

try this , these is for  static data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tekxjtView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

for dynamic data use 
gridlayout and use the above code as Adapter layout

Comment: Thx for answer! But these obj must be add programmatically. I'll take a look at this gridview!

Comment: try my same layout file programatically ..it will give same result